# Removing Django allauth change email page

Tags: python, django

I'd like to remove the Django allauth change email page and all of its functionalities that come with it. I know I can make a template for allauth and use my custom pages and deleting that page and removing all the functionalities associated with it manually, but I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this. I am afraid once I start removing the change email page functionalities something will start breaking. Is there a way to remove this page without breaking anything?

Comment: for one of my projects I used nginx to block these pages

Comment: @aliva How did you change the table set up of emails where it has `primary` as a column? Did you delete the column `primary?

Comment: I didn't change that, I simply blocked pages in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `allauth` views selectively (*i.e.*, defining in your URL patterns only the ones you need).

If it's really just this one that you want to avoid, you can also add a URL path that associates the same path `allauth` uses for this view to you 404 page; of course, you need to add it **before** importing `allauth` paths.

Something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    # Shadow undesired page
    path("account/email", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='404.html')),
    # AllAuth paths - the shadowed one won't be reachable
    path("account/", include('account.urls')),
    ...
]
```